# Cant install colorthief

Tags: npm, color-thief

I ran into somewhat of a problem while trying to run
`npm i colorthief`

I get many error messages, among them:

> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7
> or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm ERR! code 1
> npm ERR! git dep preparation failed

Is this library no longer supported?

Answer (score -1):

You should try to **import** it from a CDN rather than installing it as an NPM dependency:

```
import ColorThief from "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.3.0/color-thief.umd.js";
```